# How can I debug with the Cloud-SDK-based Maven App Engine plugin?

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, gcloud, maven-gae-plugin, appengine-maven-plugin

I'd like to debug with the  Cloud-SDK Based Maven plugin  (*com.google.cloud.tools::appengine-maven-plugin v. 1.3.0*).

I run the goal *appengine:run* in Eclipse  in Debug, but  this does not put me into Debug mode, e.g. stopping on breakpoints.

I can use remote-debugger, but it is a hassle to run two processes every time I need to start my application. Is there a way of running a Debug session with one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way to do this with Maven is by setting up a remote debug configuration in Eclipse as described in the [App Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-maven).

```
<configuration>
  <jvmFlags>
    <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
    <jvmFlag>-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005</jvmFlag>
  </jvmFlag>
</configuration>
```

Your eclipse remote debug configuration needs to use the port specified in the jvmFlag arguments.

Another more practical way to run the debugger is to use [Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/running-and-debugging).